# Javascript: scope and preserving values

Tags: javascript, scope

I have this piece of code which visualizes the tile set of a game I'm working on

```
for(var i = 0;i<=grid;i++){
    var $row = document.createElement('div');
    $row.className = 'row';

    for (var j = 0; j <= grid; j++) {
        var $tile = document.createElement('div'),
            position = {x:j,y:i};

        $tile.className = 'tile';
        $tile.onclick = function(){
            console.log(position);
            engine.popTile(position);
        }

        $row.appendChild($tile);
    }

    $holder.appendChild($row);
}
```

But I'm having this problem, on each tile the position is `x:15,y:15`. Now I'm assuming that's because I'm firing off the onclick function long after the loops had finished doing their business. My question is - how can I preserve the position data for the onclick function without adding it to the DOM?

I also tried moving the declaration of `position` inside the `onclick` function, but with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can preserve the value of `position` by returning the function from another function and passing the `position` as a parameter to the top level function, like this

```
$tile.onclick = (function(pos) {
    return function() {}
        engine.popTile(pos);
    }
})(position);
```

Now the outer function retains the current value of `position` in the parameter `pos` and that will be available to the inner function as well.

Comment: Awesome! My only concern is, as this looks kind of complicated, if this would be any harsh on the system? I mean that basically if I had 1024 tiles, that meant 1024 functions. But now as I see it they are up to 2048 which is frustrating me a bit? :D

Comment: `onclick` of every `$tile` object needs its own function. If you want them to share the same function, then your program would become little complicated. I would say, this is better.

Answer (score 1):

This type of for loops does not have its own scope block so the closure for the onClick is always referring to the same position variable. Adding a var in front of position does not create a new instance of position variable (see variable hoisting).

You can create a scope block by doing something like this:

```
var $tile = document.createElement('div'),
            position = {x:i,y:j};

for(var i = 0;i<=grid;i++){
    var $row = document.createElement('div');
    $row.className = 'row';

    for (var j = 0; j <= grid; j++) {
        (function(){
            var $tile = document.createElement('div'),
                position = {x:i,y:j};
            $tile.className = 'tile';
            $tile.onclick = function(){
                console.log(position);
                engine.popTile(position);
            }
            $row.appendChild($tile);
        }());
    }

    $holder.appendChild($row);
}
```

But perhaps creating createRow and createCell functions would be cleaner.